# Updating an Angular resource when dependent value changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I've recently joined a team working on an Angular app that's roughly (paraphrasing) laid out as follows:

```
this.appModule = angular.module( 'MainApp', ['MainApp.resourceModule', 'MainApp.configModule', 'MainApp.controllerModule'] );
this.resourceModule = angular.module( 'MainApp.resourceModule', [] );
this.configModule = angular.module( 'MainApp.configModule', [] );
this.controllerModule = angular.module( 'MainApp.controllerModule', [] );

this.configModule.value('API_SETTINGS',{'host':'http://XX.XX.XX.XX'}); 

this.resourceModule.factory('ThisResource', function($http, $resource, API_SETTINGS) {
    return $resource(API_SETTINGS.host + "/api/resource/:id", {id: "@id"});
});

this.controllerModule.controller( 'MainController', function($scope, $location, $routeParams, ThisResource ) {
    // ...
    ThisResource.get( {id: $routeParams.user_id}, function(response) { /* ... */ } );

    // ...
```

We have a form that allows you to change the value of API_SETTINGS.host (say, to "http://YY.YY.YY.YY"), however any new value entered on the form is not "recognized" by Angular ie. the resource remains attached to the original address of "http://XX.XX.XX.XX/api/resource/:id" and never changes.

What is the best way to get Angular to refresh the resource so that all objects using it reference the updated value of API_SETTINGS?  Preferably without having to change any references to the resource in other objects...is that possible?

Thanks for any help,
gs.

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing the full code. Can you assemble a minimal test case on codepen or jsfiddle? BTW, are you using ng-class on the form field and have you read the documentation about the gotchas with ng-class?

Comment: Change it from a value provider to a factory. Their example in the docs is pretty similar to your situation

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#factory-recipe

Comment: maybe it is possible to set the host as a param   return $resource( ":host/api/resource/:id", {id: "@id",host:API_SETTINGS.host});    (not tested)